Worker gets to own all the land that he can mark between sunrise and sunset
The movie itself was old. It was about human greed, exploitation and capacity.
In the feudal societies of Europe, some landholders had a gambling program. The deal was: a chosen worker was allowed to mark land, as much as he can, from sunrise to sunset, and he would be the owner (I don't remember if there was competition among workers or not, but it makes sense that the winner be the one who has marked more than others).
No worker ever becomes landholder! They ran so hard to mark more lands that by the sunset they died. In fact the landholders were aware of choosing with whom they made the deal. I remember a scene in which they were eating and laughing at a table and watching the greedy workers who were running to mark more lands.

Sounds like a version of Tolstoy's short story How Much Land Does a Man Need?

@SystemDown: There is a movie with the name you mentioned production of 2000 which is not old enough.

It's an old and famous short story, so I'm sure there are other versions (if not by the same name). I know I've seen an older one, though it doesn't match your description.
